# Completion of a Field at a Prime Ideal

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Suppose $K$ is a number field and $P$ is some prime ideal of $K,$ i.e. a prime ideal of the ring of integers in $K, \mathcal{O}_K.$

I encountered a term "completion of $K$ at $P$", but I am unsure of what that would mean. I am familiar with completions with respect to a norm, is this something similar?

Comment: A prime $P$ determines a norm on $K$, simply by taking some $0<\epsilon<1$ and defining $|x|=\epsilon^{-v_P(x)}$ where $v_P$ is the valuation of the element with respect to the prime $P$. Now just complete with respect to this norm (try doing this with $p\in\mathbb{Z}$).

Comment: @GeorgeR Thank you! Could you maybe also clarify what $v_P(x)$ would be, since $P$ is an ideal, and $x$ is an element of $K?$

Comment: So for an integer $x\in\mathcal{O}_K$, you could define $v_P(x)$ to be the greatest integer $n$ such that $x\in P^n$, so in the rational integers, this just corresponds to the power of $p$ in the prime factorisation of $x$ (in fact if you go away and read about Dedekind domains, you can remove the 'rational' from my previous statement and it still makes sense!). Then for an arbitrary non-zero element of the field, you can write it as a quotient of integers, and take the difference of their valuations.

Comment: So to be explicit in the rationals if you have a prime $p$ and a fraction $x=\frac{a}{b}$, then we can write it uniquely as $x=p^{k}\frac{m}{n}$ where $m,n$ are coprime to $p$. Then $v_p(x)=k$.

Answer (score 2):

The completion with respect to P can be defined as "Cauchy sequences in K modulo null sequences"  Both the "Cauchy" and the "null" can be defined either in terms of making $|x_n - x_m|_P$ or $|x_n-y_n|_P$  small or in terms of making $\nu _P(x_n-x_m)$ or $\nu _P(x_n-y_n)$ large. In some contexts it is easier or more natural to work with norms; in other contexts it is easier or more natural to work with valuations. As well as number fields, you can apply these ideas to function fields, where you start with a discrete valuation ring. Note that, for number fields, the $\epsilon$ of George R's comment used to go from a valuation to a norm can in general be chosen arbitrarily between 0 and 1 but if you want certain additional formulae to work, such as Artin's product formula for norms, then $\epsilon$ must be defined in terms of numbers associated with certain field extensions.